# Connection Timeout when downloading json file from url

Tags: java, json, httpconnection

I am trying to download JSON file from this URL: http://map01.eniro.no/search/search.json?index=yp&profile=pl&q=ma%C5%82opolskie&sortOrder=default&pageSize=5 in Java, but I always getting an exception:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL: http://map01.eniro.no/search/search.json
type Exception report
message Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL: http://map01.eniro.no/search/search.json
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL: http://map01.eniro.no/search/search.json
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    MainServlet.callURL(MainServlet.java:108)
    MainServlet.doGet(MainServlet.java:71)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL: http://map01.eniro.no/search/search.json
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    MainServlet.callURL(MainServlet.java:102)
    MainServlet.doGet(MainServlet.java:71)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

This is my function for this task. I tried a lot of different ways to solve this problem but I always get the same. I dont have much experience with HTTP connection programming so I need help.

```java
public static void callURL() throws IOException {

    URL obj = new URL("http://map01.eniro.no/search/search.json");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.124 Safari/537.36");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "pl-PL;q=0.8");

    String urlParameters = "?index=yp&profile=pl&q=małopolskie&sortOrder=default&pageSize=5";

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + myURL);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    System.out.println(response.toString());
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I check my http request by Fiddler app and I have an error in it:

' Incorrectly formed Request-Line. abs_path was empty (e.g. missing /). RFC2616 '

What does it mean? I thought that request is correct, because in browser I can read this json.

Comment: I think post is not supported by url u r calling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

405 is `Method Not Allowed`. The fact that you have parameters on a querystring suggests you should be doing a `GET` not a `POST`

I would try changing
`con.setRequestMethod("POST");` to `con.setRequestMethod("GET");`.

Comment: Doesnt solve my problem. But I was wondering if is possible that server can have some kind of protection?

Comment: What is the error since changing the POST to GET? Is it still exactly the same or is it a bit different now?

Comment: The same. But I alredy found where was the problem. I added "Connection" - "keep alive" to request header and now it works. Thx for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

as you wanted to get something from server you should make `GET` request instead of `POST`.

Try this,

```
private static JSONObject getResult() throws JSONException {

        String uri = "http://map01.eniro.no/search/search.json?index=yp&profile=pl&q=ma%C5%82opolskie&sortOrder=default&pageSize=5";

        JSONObject jsonResponse = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(uri);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (conn.getInputStream())));

            String jsonResponseString = br.readLine();

            jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResponseString);

            conn.disconnect();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        } catch (JSONException ex) {

        }
        System.out.println("res: " + jsonResponse);
        return jsonResponse;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, doesnt helped ;/ Still have time out error.

Comment: I am wondering why it's not working for you. I personally executed same code on my machine for above uri and its giving me resultant JSON in response.